# Accessing RFID reader on client with MVC 5 .net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, client, hardware

I am developing a browser based application which will read RFID whose driver is stored on the client machine on specific location say c:\RFIDReader.exe.

When this application will run it will return the id number as output.

I am able to read the output if I run this application on the server machine (So far I have only tried in debug mode).

But the actual problem is this application will be running on the client machine and the device (scanner) will attach to the client machine.

I am not able to figure it out how can I do that because on the client machine the only browser is the mediator talking to the server.

I am sure this is possible because there is lot of websites which accesses their service application running on client machine for example [screanleap.com](http://www.screenleap.com/)

Anyone can suggest me what can I do to access the RFIDReader.exe and get the output back and send it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how screanleap works but I would think is the same as teamviewer. In the link I see

> a quick one-time download may be required

This suggest that the client machine have a client made by screanleap running that will communicate with the server.

I would suggest making a client app that will launch RFIDReader.exe and send the info to server.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply @Bob. but can you please elaborate or give some link that will help me creating client app that will launch RFIDReader.exe and send the info to server.

Comment: Sorry don't have a link. Im referencing from my other project. You will just have to make a console app that will launch RFIDReader.exe and get the id, then send that to your server with the machine identity. Your server have to receive it maybe via WCF or other ways.